# Why string comparison results are not printing 0,1, or -1 in Java?

Tags: java, date

I have to compare a date and check that it is within a range. I have taken two dates as input such that one is the start date and another is the finish date. The compared date should not be before the start date or after the finish date.

I have taken all of them as strings and split them all.

When I am comparing the date with the start date it is ok. But when comparing with the finish date's month, it is showing a result of `6`. It should show the result of `1, 0, or -1`, since I am comparing strings.

Below is the source and I have commented above the line where I am having issues. A sample input and output is also given.  Where have I made a mistake?

```
System.out.println("................");

//store the value of start date limit.
String[] startDate  =   start_jTextField1.getText().split("-");

//store the value of start date limit.
String[] finishDate =   finish_jTextField2.getText().split("-");

//store the date that have to check.
String[] check_this_date = Check_this_Date_jTextField1.getText().split("-");

System.out.println("start:");
for(String start : startDate )
{
    System.out.println(start);
}

System.out.println("Finish:");
for(String finish : finishDate )
{
    System.out.println(finish);
}

System.out.println("Check:");
for(String checkDate : check_this_date )
{
    System.out.println(checkDate);
}


boolean start_range_check   = false;
boolean finish_range_check  = false;

//My question is about the next line and why it is printing 6.
//It should print 0, 1, or -1.
System.out.println("Before Finish check block(month):\n"+ check_this_date[1].compareTo( finishDate[1] ) );

System.out.println("Before Finish check block(day compare):\n"+ check_this_date[0].compareTo( finishDate[0] ) );//here date will be compared with finish date's date.

if( check_this_date[2].compareTo(startDate[2]) == 1 ||  check_this_date[2].compareTo(startDate[2]) == 0)//if year greater or equal to from start range year.
{
    System.out.println("starZone:"+start_range_check);//print the current start_range_check  value to ensure that above condition has satisfied.
    if(check_this_date[1].compareTo(startDate[1]) == 1 ||  check_this_date[1].compareTo(startDate[1]) == 0)//if month greater or equal to from start range month.
    {
        System.out.println("starZone:"+start_range_check);//print the current start_range_check  value to ensure that above condition has satisfied.
        if(check_this_date[0].compareTo(startDate[0]) == 1 ||  check_this_date[0].compareTo(startDate[0]) == 0)//if day greater or equal to from start range day.
        {
            start_range_check = true;
            System.out.println("starZone:"+start_range_check);//print the current start_range_check  value to ensure that above condition has satisfied and start_range_check changed.
        }
    }
}

if(check_this_date[2].compareTo( finishDate[2] ) == -1 || check_this_date[2].compareTo( finishDate[2] ) == 0 )
{
    System.out.println("finishZone result(year):\n"+check_this_date[2].compareTo( finishDate[2]) );//print the comparision result.

    System.out.println("finishZone(before month checking):\n"+check_this_date[1].compareTo( finishDate[1]) );//print the comparision result.my question why the result is 6 here.

    if(check_this_date[1].compareTo( finishDate[1] ) == -1 || check_this_date[1].compareTo( finishDate[1] ) == 0 )
    {
        System.out.println("finishZone"+start_range_check);
        if(check_this_date[0].compareTo( finishDate[0] ) == -1 || check_this_date[0].compareTo( finishDate[0] ) == 0 )
        {
            finish_range_check = true;
            System.out.println("finishZone"+start_range_check);//print the current start_range_check  value to ensure that above condition has satisfied and start_range_check changed.
        }
    }
}

if( finish_range_check == true && start_range_check == true )
{
    result_jLabel2.setText("Within Range.");
}
else
{
    result_jLabel2.setText("Not in Range");
}


Sample input and output:
Date Format: dd-MM-yyyy
................
start:
28
6
2015
Finish:
28
12
2015
Check:
28
7
2015
Before Finish check block(month comparing):
6
Before Finish check block(day comparing):
0
starZone:false
starZone:false
starZone:true
finishZone result(year):
0
finishZone(before month checking):
6
```

Comment: Why not parse it into a `Date` object and work with that instead?  It would be far less complex and far more reliable than breaking up the individual string portions into date fragments.

Comment: compareTo doesn't return -1 or 0 or 1, see the apidoc: "Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."

Comment: Do you really need to convert the dates into strings? Make use of `after` and `before` methods from Date API.

Comment: @Dariusz Sendkowski, no it is not necessary. actually  don't know about those method. i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andreas has told that why you should compare the result with 0, not with 1 or -1. And @Nick Miller has given more theoretical details.

I am agree with  @Makoto and @Dariusz Sendkowski that it is complex in the the way you are trying.

Here is an example solution of your problem. More details and examples are in the following link. There are also some other ways to do this.

```
  SimpleDateFormat setDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");

        try
          {
            Date startDate  = setDateFormat.parse( start_jTextField1.getText()  );
            Date finishDate = setDateFormat.parse( finish_jTextField2.getText() );
            Date check_this_date = setDateFormat.parse( Check_this_Date_jTextField1.getText() );

              System.out.println("Start Date:"+ setDateFormat.format(startDate));
              System.out.println("Finish Date:"+ setDateFormat.format(finishDate));

            if( check_this_date.before(finishDate) && check_this_date.after(startDate))
              {
                  result_jLabel2.setText("Within Range.");
              }
            else if(check_this_date.equals(finishDate) || check_this_date.equals(startDate))
              {
                result_jLabel2.setText("Within Range.");
              }
            else
              {
                 result_jLabel2.setText("Not in rannge.");
              }
          }
        catch(Exception ex)
          {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

[More examples are here...](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

Answer (score 4):

Read the javadoc of [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> Returns a **negative integer**, **zero**, or a **positive integer** as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

It doesn't specify the actual value of the negative or positive number, so you cannot expect it to be `-1` or `1`.

When using `compareTo()` you should always check result as `< 0`, `<= 0`, `== 0`, `>= 0`, `> 0`, or `!= 0`, depending on your need.
Basically `date1.compareTo(date2) <= 0` is Java-speak for `date1 <= date2`.

Answer (score 1):

[Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639970/975724) isn't quite complete.

While this is true, it doesn't explain why it is so.

[The derivation still comes from the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

> This is the definition of lexicographic ordering. If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let k be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position k has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the two character values at position k in the two string -- that is, the value:
>
> `this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)`

In other words, the value returned is the lexicographical difference of the first two (same-indexed) characters that don't match.  Which is a reason why you may not receive `-1` or `1`.

The javadoc continues:

> If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, compareTo returns the difference of the lengths of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> `this.length()-anotherString.length()`

Which is yet another reason for the different numbers returned.

This is why you **must compare using inequalities** to determine which string is lexicographically greater or lesser than another string.